# Date reformatting within a loop

Tags: batch-file

Hopefully this is a simple question, but I've been tearing my hair out (and I ain't got much left).

```
echo
for /r "i:\Podcasts\%foldername%\" %%i in (*.mp3) do (
    set FILEDATE=%%~ti
    set FILEYEAR=%FILEDATE:~6,4%
)
exit /b
```

FILEDATE looks okay. I can't figure out why FILEYEAR isn't getting populated ... it's showing as FILEYEAR=~6,4.

In your responses, I'd like to avoid using EnableDelayedExpansion if possible (this is part of a larger batch routine).

Thx

Comment: Try `call set "FILEYEAR=%%FILEDATE:~6,4%%"`...

Comment: Thx for the response. No joy.

Comment: I missed the above 'question already answered' part ... so the answer is: call ECHO set "FILEYEAR=%%FILEDATE:~6,4%%"